# htaccess redirect to folder if cookie is missing

Tags: .htaccess, cookies

I would like to check within the htaccess if a cookie has a special value. If not I would like to redirect all requests to a login page "/login/". This step is working fine.

But now **I have to exclude the login page** to avoid endless redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie-name=test [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/login/ [NC,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the special value **-** as a "substition", which is effectively the same as *don't do anything*. This will prevent further rewrite processing if the user is already on the login page.

I also removed the rewrite condition that checks if you're on the login page because it's no longer needed. I also removed the host name from the bottom rewrite rule and replaced it with a relative URL `/login/`, but you may have a good reason to do it your way.

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie-name=test [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /login/ [NC,L]
```